# How can I limit the copy speed of a shared file on the network?

Tags: windows, network-monitor, bandwidth

I have a network of 20 PC's all running windows 7, I shared some large files from my own PC, and the copying speed in the network is about 30Mbs to 60Mbs.

What I want to do is to limit that speed down to 3Mbs for every PC on the LAN, so every PC gets 3Mbs of file transfer speed without interrupting with the browsing traffic, or causing lag while browsing the network.

I used NetBalancer on my PC, but it gave all PCs on the network 3Mbs at once, and created a horrible lag!

I customized the supercopier2 program to copy files at 3Mbs speed, but when someone wants to copy something from and to his own portable drives it gets very slow.

I need a software that gives me ability to slow down the traffic of only my shared files and with speed limit of 3Mbs for each PC. and I don't mind installing a client and server apps over the network.

(Sorry for my English btw)

Comment: Does using `robocoppy.exe` in the form of a batch script with user input not work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to use robocopy, so If there's a tutorial on how to set up a patch. and does robocopy work as the internal explorer.exe copier or what?..Thanx

Comment: Look on SS64 for robocopy! It's an internal dos command.